# Nginx 413 Request Entity Too Large, Docker, Django

Tags: django, docker, nginx

I get hit with the error

> 413 Request Entity Too Large

when I try to upload any file larger than 1.5MB.

I have seen various answers out there regarding this issue but nothing seems to work with my situation:

**my nginx default.conf:**

```
upstream django {
    server store:27038;
}

server {

    listen 27036;

    location /static {
        alias /vol/static;
    }
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

**my nginx Dockerfile:**

```
FROM nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:1-alpine


COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

USER root

RUN mkdir -p /vol/static
RUN chmod 777 /vol/static

USER nginx
```

I keep on seeing responses saying that just adding something like

```
server {
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    ...
}
```

somewhere in Nginx should solve the issue but I keep getting an error when I try to put it on my conf file so am not entirely sure where this code is supposed to go. If anyone has an answer for this it would be much appreciated

Comment: What error do you get when you add the `client_max_body_size` directive to the config?

Comment: ... actually you questioning me just made me realize that the error I was getting is suddenly gone. It works perfectly for whatever reason now. Not sure what the issue was but I went back, deleted the old image and once I rebuilt it it worked fine! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So funny enough there seemed to be some sort of caching issue on my dockerfile so the changes didn't properly take effect, thus the reason why the solution wasn't working:

```
upstream django {
    server store:27038; 
}

server {

    client_max_body_size 100M;
    listen 27036;

    location /static {
        alias /vol/static;
    }
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

This did the trick for me. Simply adding the `client_max_body_size 100M` and rebuilding the image from scratch.